# overload in step find element

Tags: java, selenium

I have selenium java code testing some site in ff 41 and selenium 2.48. Last step of my code is `findElement` (timeout 30 sec). I don't have any error and my test does not fail. But I see overload in this step, its duration is 88 - 150 sec.
Any idea why my test does not fail after 30 sec?
Here is my last step code

```
errorMessage = "";
boolean flag23 = false;
for (int k = 0; k < 30; k++)
{
    try
    {
        List<WebElement> element23 = findElements("print-confirmation");// "//a[@class='print-confirmation']");
        if (element23.size() != 0)
        {
            flag23 = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        pause(1000);
    }
}
assertTrue(flag23); // new WebDriverWait(driver,
                    // 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("//a[@class='print-confirmation']")));
writer.append("\ntest89028:23 OK " + getRunTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you call `findElements` 30 times and you pause 1s after each iteration if you do not find your element yet. So you need worst case 30s only for pausing, plus time for the whole loop and especially for `findElements`. So your recorded time is more than 30s, since you record the whole code block execution. I don't know if I got it right and this might help you.

Comment: it's interesting , but do you thing that it will increase the execution time of this code 2 times and even 4 ?

Comment: Well, it seems bit too much, you're right...but I don't know the complexity of your `findElements` method. You get back a List of WebElements each iteration, and depending on your method it might take a while to create and return that list. But this is just a guess, hope you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is in the `findElements()` function... maybe a wait or sleep? Something in there is likely magnifying the wait time or you have an `implicitWait()` set. I would rewrite this block of code like this... (and remove any `implicitWait()`).

```
boolean flag23 = false;
try
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='print-confirmation']")));
    flag23 = true;
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    System.out.println("Element not found due to TimeoutException");
}
assertTrue(flag23);
```

I think it's easier to read and is more controlled. You should not mix implicit and explicit waits or you will get weird behaviors (likely similar to this).

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits

> WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example setting an implicit wait of 10s and an explicit wait of 15 seconds, could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.